# "Inverting" the Artin map in terms of characters

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I will start by saying that I know very little about Class Field Theory, so I am hoping for someone to shed some light on this.

If $K$ is a finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then one can build a map $\phi$ from the set of all but finitely many prime numbers to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ by composing the Artin map with a nontrivial character of the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, i.e.
$$ \phi : p \mapsto \left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right) \mapsto \chi\left(\left(\frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{p}\right)\right), $$
and then extend it to almost all integers by multiplicativity.

If the extension has degree 2, then $\phi$ is simply the Kronecker symbol
$$ \phi(n) = \left(\frac{\Delta}{n}\right),$$
and by Quadratic Reciprocity, this is a character modulo $\Delta$.

I was wondering if something similar can be done for higher-degree extensions, say if $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$, can we express $\phi$ as a character of some finite group?

Comment: $\phi$ is always a Dirichlet character : the main point of CFT for $\Bbb{Q}$ is [that any abelian extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subfield of a cyclotomic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem) whose Artin map  and characters are easy to find

Comment: @reuns Could you elaborate a bit? I now get how this works for cyclotomic extensions but not in the general case.

Comment: If $K \subset \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ then $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})=G/H,G=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\Bbb{Q})/ H, H = Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/K)$ and the Artin map is $(\frac{I}{K/\Bbb{Q}}) =( \frac{I}{\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\Bbb{Q}}) H\in G/H$ and any character of $G/H$ is a character of $G$